# Time counter for traffic lights wont increment

Tags: vhdl

I am writing simple intersection "simulator" for assignment. It goes like this: 
User inputs amount of cars which stopped at traffic lights on every lane and defines times of changing lights. When the timer value is equal to the time defined by user, lights should change their colors.

Problem apperas in time_counter, process looks like this

```
 time_counter_process: process (reset, clk)
begin
if reset = '1' then
    time_counter<=  "0000000";
elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
        if (state = state_1 and time_counter < state_1_time_value) then
            -- in state_1 one some lights are green and others red, simple
            time_counter <= time_counter + 1;

                if (state = state_1 and time_counter = state_1_time_value) then
                    time_counter <= "0000000";
                end if;

        etc...

        elsif state = state_6 and time_counter < state_6_time_value then

            time_counter <= time_counter + 1;

                if state = state_6 and time_counter = state_6_time_value then
                    time_counter <= "0000000";
                end if;


    end if;
end if;
end process time_counter_process;
```

I don't know why, but the timer is not incrementing properly. It stays at the value "000000". Can someone tell me why it is not working correctly?

For more clarity i will also show how the states are changing

```
    begin
next_state<= state;
case state is
when state_1 =>
    if time_counter < state_1_time_value then
            traffic_signal_1 <= "10"; --green
            traffic_signal_2 <= "00"; -- red
            traffic_signal_3 <= "00";   
            traffic_signal_4 <= "10";
            traffic_signal_5 <= "00";
            traffic_signal_6 <= "00";


            elsif time_counter = state_1_time_value then

                    next_state<=state_2;
            end if;
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation, so we can read and understand your code. You should exchange the big *if*-statement with a *case*-statement for `state` and implement the counter condition as an *if*-statement in each *when*-choice. Conditions like `time_counter = state_1_time_value` will never be true, because, signal are updated at the end of a process. You are in a branch where `time_counter < state_1_time_value` is true, so `time_counter = state_1_time_value` can not also be true.

Comment: If you use the mentioned *case*-statements with *when*-choices, you can rewrite your `if (state = state_1 and time_counter = state_1_time_value) then` to an `else`-branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exchange the big *if*-statement with a *case*-statement for `state` and implement the counter condition as an *if*-statement in each *when*-choice.

Conditions like `time_counter = state_1_time_value` will never be true, because, signal are updated at the end of a process. You are in a branch where `time_counter < state_1_time_value` is true, so `time_counter = state_1_time_value` can not also be true.

```
time_counter_process: process (reset, clk)
begin
  if (reset = '1') then
    time_counter<=  "0000000";
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    case state is
      when state_1 =>
        if (time_counter < state_1_time_value) then
          -- in state_1 one some lights are green and others red, simple
          time_counter <= time_counter + 1;
        else
          time_counter <= "0000000";
        end if;

-- etc...

    when state_6 =>
      if (time_counter < state_6_time_value) then
        time_counter <= time_counter + 1;
      else
        time_counter <= "0000000";
      end if;

    end case;
  end if;
end process time_counter_process;
```

Btw, you should prefer synchronous resets in your design.